# Writing to textfile using getFilesdir in Android

Tags: android

I am writing some data to external storage using Environment variable. It works fine. I would like to try to write to internal storage. I get an error when I use the following code.

```
public class B{
  public void write(long l){  
  File root = new File(getFilesDir(), "Traces"); 
  File gpxfile = new File(root, "Collection.txt");
  if(gpxfile.exists()){
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile,true);
    writer.append(Long.toString(l));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
        }
```

The error I am getting is 'The method getFilesDir() is undefined' Create method getFilesDir(). I tried assigning context. Something like

```
context.getFilesDir()
```

and defining

```
Context context = MainActivity();% in main activity from where I am calling this writefunction.
```

Comment: Not sure what your error is. The method is getFilesDir() with a capital D

Comment: from the previous posts I have seen that I need to add a context. I did that. But not sure what mistake I did

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

or it may be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STROAGE"/>
```

you can check them both.

Comment: I just reread your question and realized you'd want the first permission, not the second. My bad lol.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I have the permission set

Comment: Hmm ok, what about something like this: `BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(getFilesDir()+File.separator+fileName.getText().toString()+".txt"));out.write(text.getText().toString());
     out.close();`

Comment: The problem is not with writer class. But getting access to getFilesDir().I tried yours and got the same error for getFilesDir

Comment: Can you post the entire method that this is in?

Comment: Maybe try `this.getFilesDir()`...?

Comment: WRITE_INTERNAL_STROAGE nor WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE permission does not exists: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html